# Name error while importing data from excel into python

Tags: python, excel

I have a name error while importing data from excel to python

```
northern.tss = xl_file.parse('northern.tss')
northern.tss.head()
```

I get:

> name 'northern' is not defined

Comment: why not using pandas or xlrd ?

Comment: Have you defined `northern`?

Comment: The dot has a special meaning in Python - you shouldn't use it in a name. Have a look here: http://reeborg.ca/docs/oop_py_en/oop.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to read xcel data by using [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('Foo.xlsx', sheetname='Bar')

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
```

Using the data frame, you can get all the rows below an entire column as a list. To get such a list, simply use the column header

```
print(df['Column name'])
```

To iterate over the list you can use a loop:

```
for i in df.index:
    print(df['Column name'][i])
```

and so on (read more about pandas DataFrame in order to learn what data manipulations are possible)

[More about pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

[How to install pandas lib](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

Comment: Thank y'all.. y'all so nice and helpful. I already made it with csv file..